# How do I make 3D plot for T, G and P as a function of $r$?

Tags: plotting, parametric-functions

I want to plot a 3D graph ('G' v/s 'P' v/s 'T') for folllowing value as
'T' in terms of `r`

```
T = 1/(4 Pi r) + 2 P r - 1/(4 Pi r^3),
```

'G' in terms of `r`

```
G = r/4 - (2 Pi P r^3))/3 + 3/(4 r).
```

and `P` in terms of `r`

```
P = T/r -1/(2 Pi r^2) + 2/(Pi r^4)
```

I want to plot for following range: `{{G, 0.2, 1.8}, {P, 0, 0.004}, {T, 0, 0.06}}`

Comment: you can use P=T/r -1/(2 pi r^2) +2/(pi r^4)

Comment: Please do not use the [tag:graphs-and-networks] tag unless the question concerns graph-theoretical graphs. You can click a tag to read what it's for. Also: format your posts. There's formatting help on the right of the edit box. Your last post was formatted by a volunteer. You can use it as an example.

Comment: Finally: you still didn't show what  you have tried. Did you look at any tutorials on plotting with Mathematica?

Comment: "ok, yes i am continously trying to plot" If you show *what exactly* you did, what your attempts so far were, then people can guide you to a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here is method for examining the relationship between `P`, `T` and `G` as functions of `r`. First we find the functions.

```
Clear[P, T, G]
{P[r_], T[r_], G[r_]} =
  Solve[
    {P == T/r - 1/(2 π r^2) + 2/(π r^4),
     T == 1/(4 π r) + 2 P r - 1/(4 π r^3),
     G == r/4 - (2 Pi P r^3)/3 + 3/(4 r)},
   {P, T, G}][[1, All, 2]]
```

[image: soon]

Then we make an interactive plot of the functions in the space `{{P, 0, 0.004}, {T, 0, 0.06}}`.

```
box =
  Graphics3D[
   {FaceForm[], EdgeForm[], Cuboid @@ Transpose[{{0, 0.004}, {0, 0.06}, {0.2, 1.8}}]},
   Boxed -> False];
Manipulate[
  Dynamic @
    Show[
      ParametricPlot3D[{P[r], T[r], G[r]}, {r, rmin, rmax},
        AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {"P", "T", "G"}),
        BoxRatios -> 1],
      box,
      PlotRange -> All],
  {rmin, .5, 15, .5, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
  {rmax, 10, 50, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image: demo]

Note: Although the above code give us reasonable control over the range or `P` and `T`, the range of `G` cannot be fixed because it is determined by the settings for `rain` and `max`.

Answer (score 0):

```
ClearAll[T, P, G, t, p, g]

t = 1/(4 Pi r) + 2 P r - 1/(4 Pi r^3);
p = T/r - 1/(2 Pi r^2) + 2/(Pi r^4);
g = r/4 - (2 Pi P r^3)/3 + 3/(4 r);

func = {G, p, T} /. Solve[Eliminate[{T == t, P == p, G == g}, P], {G, T}, Reals][[1]];
```

> {(23 + r^2)/(12 r),
>    2/(π r^4) - 1/(2 π r^2) + (-15 + 3 r^2)/(
>     4 π r^4),
>   (-15 + 3 r^2)/(4 π r^3)}

```
Quiet @ ParametricPlot3D[func, {r, 0, 10 Pi}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0.2, 1.8}, {0, 0.004}, {0, 0.06}}, BoxRatios -> 1]
```

[image]